# RuntimeException using Apache POI to export excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

For the past couple of days, this has been driving me crazy.
Here are the codes that are supposed to evaluate cells in an attached template  test.xlsx

```
    public static void updateFormule(String testcode, byte[] excelFile, String fileName, 
            String testcode, Boolean update, Test test){
        Workbook wb = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;  
        String testerror= "";
    SomeCode...
        try {
            if(fileName != null)
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF8")); 
                wb = getWorkbookReader(getSrcInputStream(excelFile));
                
//          AverageIF averageIF = new AverageIF();
            try {
                WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("AVERAGEIF", AverageIF.instance);
                WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("EOMONTH", EOMonth.instance);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                // TODO: handle exception
//              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

When it comes to

> wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();

Unfortunately this is what I get upon execution:

```
Invalid sheetIndex: -1
```

Comment: If you evaluate each cell individually (by looping over all the rows and cells), can you identify the formula that triggers the issue?

Comment: Must be a formula referencing another sheet (which probably no longer exists) or even an external workbook with a sheet that no longer exists

Comment: @Gagravarr plz how can i identify it ?

Comment: As he said, `by looping over all the rows and cells`. `FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); for(int i=0; i<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);for(Row r : sheet) {for (Cell c : r) {if (c.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);}}}}` <-- taken from `BaseFormulaEvaluator` source code